# After update flutter some errors displaying and after fix not working my code

Tags: flutter, dart

after updating flutter version 2   display some errors and fix after not working my code
also I'm update the http dependencies http: ^0.13.1 into new version

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart'as http;

class SudentClassView extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_SudentClassViewState createState() => _SudentClassViewState();
}

class _SudentClassViewState extends State<SudentClassView> {

 Future<List> getData() async{
 var url = Uri.parse('http://eduapp.studysmile.lk/studentclass');

 final response = await http.get(url);

return json.decode(response.body);  print('Response status:');
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Home Menu'),),
  body:FutureBuilder<List>(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (ctx,ss){//print(ss);
        if(ss.hasError)
        {
          print('errors');
        }
        if(ss.hasData)
        {
          return Classes(list:ss.data);
        }
        else
        {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      }
  ),
);
 }
    }

class Classes extends StatelessWidget {
List list;
Classes({this.list});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: list == null?0:list.length,
    itemBuilder: (ctx,i){
      return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment(0.2, 0.6),
              child: Text(list[i]['fldClassName'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),)
          ),
          color: Color(0xff7c4dff),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: (){
          },


        ),
      );
    }
);
}
}
```

> please help solve my problem . displaying this error message
>
> I/chatty  (11831): uid=10163(com.example.studysmile_project) 1.ui
> identical 8 lines I/flutter (11831): errors

Comment: Show more details about the error, more stacktrace.